# Null value in column of relation violates not-null constraint - NestJS

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

So. I've setup pretty much everything for the creation of my Item. When i try to run it in Postman i get the error named in the title. The concerning column is `cancellation` from the table "Item". In postman, I clearly define it as true (which is not null). And also interesting is the fact that it doesn't complain about the `delivery` column which is the exact same type as `cancellation`

**The error message:**
[image: error message in question]

**Postman screenshot:**
[image]

**Item entity**

```
import { Category } from './category.entity';
import { Rent } from './rent.entity';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import {
  BaseEntity,
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity('item')
export class Item {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column()
  price: number;

  @Column()
  delivery: boolean;

  @Column()
  cancellation: boolean;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  rating: number;

  @Column()
  imageUrl: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.items, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  user: User;

  @OneToOne(() => Rent, (rent) => rent.item)
  rent: Rent;

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, (category) => category.items)
  @JoinTable()
  categories: Category[];
}
```

**Create item DTO**

```
import {
  IsBoolean,
  IsNotEmpty,
  IsNumber,
  IsOptional,
  IsString,
} from 'class-validator';

export class CreateItemDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  description: string;

  @IsNumber()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  price: number;

  @IsBoolean()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  delivery: boolean;

  @IsBoolean()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  cancellation: boolean;

  @IsOptional()
  rating: number;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  userId: number;

  @IsOptional()
  imageUrl: string;
}
```

**User entity**

```
import { Item } from './item.entity';
import { Rent } from './rent.entity';
import { Review } from './review.entity';
import {
  BaseEntity,
  Column,
  Entity,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity('user')
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  name: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  surname: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  street: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  city: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 5 })
  zip: string;

  @Column({ type: 'int', nullable: true })
  rating: number;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 10 })
  phone: string;

  @Column('date')
  date: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 50, nullable: false, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 75, nullable: false })
  password: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Review, (review) => review.user)
  reviews: Review[];

  @OneToMany(() => Rent, (rent) => rent.user)
  rents: Rent[];

  @OneToMany(() => Item, (item) => item.user)
  items: Item[];
}
```

**Items service**

```
import { CreateItemDto } from './dto/createItem.dto';
import { ItemsRepository } from './items.repository';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Item } from 'src/entities/item.entity';
import { User } from 'src/entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(ItemsRepository)
    private itemsRepository: ItemsRepository,
  ) {}

  async getItemById(id: number) {
    return await this.itemsRepository.findOne(id);
  }

  async createItem(createItemDto: CreateItemDto, user: User): Promise<Item> {
    const newItem = await this.itemsRepository.save({
      name: createItemDto.name,
      description: createItemDto.description,
      price: createItemDto.price,
      delivery: createItemDto.delivery,
      rating: createItemDto.rating,
      imageUrl: createItemDto.imageUrl,
    });

    user.items = [...user.items, newItem];
    await user.save();

    return newItem;
  }
}
```

**Items controller**

```
import { AuthService } from './../auth/auth.service';
import { CreateItemDto } from './dto/createItem.dto';
import { ItemsService } from './items.service';
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Item } from 'src/entities/item.entity';

@Controller('items')
export class ItemsController {
  constructor(
    private itemsService: ItemsService,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  @Post('/createitem')
  async createItem(@Body() createItemDto: CreateItemDto): Promise<Item> {
    const user = await this.authService.getUserById(createItemDto.userId);
    return this.itemsService.createItem(createItemDto, user);
  }
}
```

**Auth service**

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { SignUpDto } from './dto/signup.dto';
import { SignInDto } from './dto/signin.dto';
import { UsersRepository } from './users.repository';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { JwtPayload } from './jwt-payload.interface';
import { User } from 'src/entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UsersRepository)
    private usersRepository: UsersRepository,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async signUp(signUpDto: SignUpDto): Promise<void> {
    return this.usersRepository.createUser(signUpDto);
  }

  async signIn(signInDto: SignInDto): Promise<{ accessToken: string }> {
    const { email, password } = signInDto;
    const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne({ email });
    if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
      const payload: JwtPayload = { email };
      const accessToken: string = await this.jwtService.sign(payload);
      return { accessToken };
    } else {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Check your login credentials');
    }
  }
  async getUserById(id: number): Promise<User> {
    return await this.usersRepository.findOne(id, { relations: ['items'] });
  }
}
```

**Items module**

```
import { AuthModule } from './../auth/auth.module';
import { AuthService } from './../auth/auth.service';
import { ItemsRepository } from './items.repository';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ItemsController } from './items.controller';
import { ItemsService } from './items.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ItemsRepository]), AuthModule],
  controllers: [ItemsController],
  providers: [ItemsService],
})
export class ItemsModule {}
```

Comment: In Items Service you have createItem, which doesn't provide a value for the field cancellation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `cancellation` property:

```
    const newItem = await this.itemsRepository.save({
  name: createItemDto.name,
  description: createItemDto.description,
  price: createItemDto.price,
  delivery: createItemDto.delivery,
  rating: createItemDto.rating,
  imageUrl: createItemDto.imageUrl,
  cancellation: createItemDto.cancellation, // this one
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added a one-to-many relationship between entities, in your Nestjs project. Or some other relationship. You can delete all the rows of the each tables in question to fix the error.

For example ins a one-to-many relationship.

**User 1-->* Task**

user.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
export class User {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true})
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({ unique: true})
  email: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Task, (task) => task.user)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id', referencedColumnName: 'userId'})
  tasks: Task[];

}
```

task.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
export class Task {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // @Column({ unique: true})
  @Column('text')
  description: string;

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: TaskStatus, default: TaskStatus.OPEN})
  status: TaskStatus;

  @Column({ name: 'created_at', type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'})
  date: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn({ name: 'deleted_at', type: 'timestamp', nullable: true })
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column({ name: 'user_id'})
  userId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.tasks)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId'})
  user: User;
}
```

Delete all rows of the two tables.

```
delete from user;
delete from task ;
```

Answer (score -3):

posting usernamne password in postman with x-www-form-data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31777395)